# Why is the mov rbp, rsp needed at the end of a function

Tags: assembly, x86

I understand the function prologue:

```
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
```

For example, if we want to use `rbp` as the reference point for the local function's stackframe, then we need to:

- Set `rbp` to the current position of the stack pointer.
- Restore the `rbp` value at the end because rsp, rbp are callee-saved.

From this, I get doing:

```
push %rbp        # save this onto the stack so we can restore it back at the end
mov %rsp, %rbp    # now we can use rbp as our 'local stack'

...

pop %rbp        # restore the rbp value
```

But why is the ending `mov %rbp, %rsp` necessary at the end? Usually it seems like it already has the same value as `rbp` anyways. Or, is this only necessary if I do an additional `push`, `pop`, or `add/sub %rsp`?

Comment: Look at a function that actually uses stack space for locals.  There will be a `sub $NNN, %rsp` immediately after `mov %rsp, %rbp`, and the `mov %rsp, %rbp` at the end effectively undoes that to put the stack back where it was. In this case a simple `add $NNN, %rsp` would also suffice, but a more complex function might adjust the stack several times, by non-constant amounts (e.g. for VLAs or `alloca`), in which case it would be a pain to keep track of them all

Comment: @NateEldredge oh I see, so it's really only required when the inner-stack frame is modified, right?

Comment: Yes, that's why GCC does in practice omit it (using only `pop %rbp`) in functions that don't change other than via push RSP.

Comment: The `leave` instruction does the same as `mov rsp,rbp; pop rbp`.

Comment: so that it is restored for the callee function to continue using.